# html DIV unnecessarily resizing with browser actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an html transparent header bar with following CSS:

```
#head-bar{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    min-height:25%;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:#000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

**The issue:**

If I enabled some browser tool-bars this div decreases it's height. The same thing happens when I enable firebug panel or firefox's console.
I tried to get over this by setting this div's height dynamically with jquery.

```
$(window).height() * 25 / 100; // unsuccessful attempt
```

How can I keep this div in a fixed state? Could you please enlighten me.

Comment: That's the purpose of pourcentage, so instead use fixed height: `$('#head-bar').height($(window).height() * 25 / 100);`  http://jsfiddle.net/Rq9vy/

Comment: having an event handler like this is not encouraged, as it would be called every time browsers height changes. instead use of percentage can be avoided and provide it a fixed height in em/px/pt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage unit is to induce flexibility to appearance with respect to browser's state.
If the height has to be retained the same always, provide the height in px/pt or better use 'em' units. Since you use percentage, every time browsers height changes, the height of the div also modified, as per the CSS rule defined (25%).

Answer (score 1):

This is your [current Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zea8m/).

And use this jQuery code to fix the issue.

```
$(function () {
    $('#head-bar').height($(window).height() * 25 / 100);
})
```

And this is [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N92Dj/) with fixed code.

Comment: This works fine. But I realized using percentage isn't a wise move. thank you @Zafar anyway.